# How Do I Create Folders On Multiple Android Devices w/ adb shell In A Batch

Tags: batch-file, adb, mkdir

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use mkdir on multiple android devices using adb shell.  Right now my script is only useful for 1 devices at a time.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@echo off
set androidPath="/sdcard"
set folder1="/folder1/"
set folder2="/folder2/" 
set folder3="/folder3/"
set test="/test_folder/"

echo Creating folder1
adb shell "mkdir %androidPath%%folder1%"
echo Creating folder2
adb shell "mkdir %androidPath%%folder2%"
echo Creating folder3
adb shell "mkdir %androidPath%%folder3%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `adb shell` with  `adb -s <adb serial number> shell cmd`. Your script should work.